# jQuery Validation in Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery Validation code in which I have written

```
element.focus();
```

When I view that page into other browser I able to modify that previous Field if I was left next field blank or wrong input.

but in chrome i wont able to do so..!

Can you please explain the reason behind this?

Thanks in Advanced...!

The Full Code of function is here..

```
function validateFullName(){
        var s=fullName.val();
        var i;
        var returnString = "";
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        var b = s.match(/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/);
        if(fullName.val().length == ''){
            fullName.addClass("error");
            fullNameInfo.text("Please enter Name.");
            fullNameInfo.addClass("error5");
            fullName.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (c == " "){
            fullName.addClass("error");
            fullNameInfo.text("Name Should Not Start With Space.");
            fullNameInfo.addClass("error5");
            fullName.focus();
            return false;
            }
        if (!b){
            fullName.addClass("error");
            fullNameInfo.text("Symbols and Numbers Not Allowed in Name.");
            fullNameInfo.addClass("error5");
            fullName.focus();
            return false;
            }
        else{
            fullName.removeClass("error");
            fullNameInfo.text("");
            fullNameInfo.removeClass("error5");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share link to live page or at least post code there.

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: with the fname.keyup(validateFullName);

Comment: fname.blur(validateFullName);